# Separating comma separated string and perform math in Excel cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

An Excel cell contains three numbers separated by comma, e.g. `2,10,3`. I want to put the result of `2*10*3` which is 60 in another cell. When I use `=SPLIT(A1,",")` (Google sheet) or `=TEXTSPLIT(A1,",")`, the result is three new columns each containing one value, that is `2    10    3`. Is there a way to put the separated numbers in an array and apply the multiplication?

UPDATE:

It seems that the proposed method doesn't work on Google sheet.
[image]

Comment: Try =arrayformula(product(--split(A1,",")))

Comment: seems to work fine in Google Sheets (without the -- ).  not clear from your question whether it's exclusively about excel?

=PRODUCT(SPLIT(A1,","))

Answer (score 0):

Your formula works quite well, as indicated by the comment by @MattKing, without the `--` which seems to convert the array resulting from `SPLIT()` into a scalar containing only its first element:

[image: GSheet solution using PRODUCT()]

In Excel you can use `TEXTSPLIT` with `REDUCE` (this approach should work in Google Sheets too, but `PRODUCT()` is simpler)

[image: Excel solution using REDUCE with a LAMBDA function]